# Activating test cases from within a test case

Tags: python, unit-testing

Is there any Python unit testing framework that allows you to add more test cases from within another test case (e.g. if something goes wrong, activate another test case to get more detailed analysis)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pytest](http://pytest.org) allows you to do pretty much anything. It has plugin support, and, probably more importantly in your case, lets you hook in any stage of the process, including test collection.

It also probably already has what you need. I am not sure what it is exactly, why you can't run all the tests all the time if you took time to write them. Probably execution time concerns?

Take a look at features pytest offers out of the box. This can be of interest to you in particular:

- attributes - http://pytest.org/latest/mark.html#mark
- conditional skipping - http://pytest.org/latest/skipping.html#skipping

If that doesn't cut it, hack away - http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#pytest-hook-reference